# Spring Boot Gradle Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

The Spring Boot reference guide provides instructions for upgrading to Tomcat 8 by setting a custom property in Maven:

```
<properties>
  <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

What is the equivalent way to do the same in a Gradle build?

I have tried the following to no avail. It stays on version 7.0.52 at app startup.

```
buildscript {
  ...    
  ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.0.3'
  ...
}
```

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2 will use tomcat 8 by default. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.2-Release-Notes#servlet-31-tomcat-8-and-jetty-9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle has no equivalent of a "parent pom", so you have to call out the dependency explicitly. Because it's groovy you can probably do it programmatically, something like:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.tomcat.embed') {
        details.useVersion '8.0.3'
    }
  }
}
```

We *could* add some support for version properties to the Spring Boot Gradle plugin (feel free to open an issue in github) but it would probably have to be optional.

Answer (score 3):

Please, have a look at Gretty plugin: it supports Tomcat 8 (as well as Tomcat 7, Jetty 7/8/9) and SpringBoot out of the box. No dependency tweaking is needed.

https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty

Disclosure: I am author of Gretty plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For setting up version of tomcat I used:

```
    dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.1.8.RELEASE'
}
```

where you just need to find which spring-boot-starter-tomcat suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could configure Spring Boot1.3.3 to work with Tomcat v8.0.33. By default it works with version 8.0.32 and that version has the Websocket problem.

```
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
  }
  //providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.33'
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.0.33'
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.0.33'
  compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.0.33'
```