# Spring Boot Gradle Tomcat 8 (build.gradle)

Tags: spring-boot

I have seen the answer to question [Spring Boot Gradle Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621132/spring-boot-gradle-tomcat-8), but I don't understand where to add the Groovy code. I have put it into build.gradle, but the application still loads with Tomcat 7.

Comment: Did you place it in `build.gradle` under the `apply plugin:***` part? Checkout http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: No, but now I have, and it works. Thanks for pointing this out. Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621132/spring-boot-gradle-tomcat-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to is place

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.tomcat.embed') {
        details.useVersion '8.0.3'
    }
  }
}
```

right under the `apply plugin: ***` section in your `build.gradle`.

Check out [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) part of the gradle documentation for more details.